# R: Dropbox Data Folder Download Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if its possible to somehow given a dropbox folder link, download all files in that folder in to R?

If not is is possible, how would one be able to upload files onto Shiny Server so maybe I could source them locally?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you used `download.file`?

Comment: The problem might be actually listing the files in the directory.

Comment: Using [rDrop](https://github.com/karthikram/rDrop), specifically ```?dropbox_dir``` and ```?dropbox_get``` would get you there although nested folders might be a slight annoyance. It does require the owner of the dropbox to authorise as discussed under _Initial Setup_.